# Force GraphLayout to put specific node at top

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've got a tree graph and I would like to have a specific node be the root in the laid-out `Graph` as well. Here's a MWE:

```
g = 
 TreeGraph[
  {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 6},
  VertexLabels -> Automatic
  ]
```

[image: bad graph]

I want, e.g. `1` to be the top-most node *without* having to compute vertex coordinates myself.

Is this possible?

Comment: Or use `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`, which will automatically find the source in a directed graph. The result will be different.

Comment: @Szabolcs I actually have an undirected graph, but that is good to know if I decided to switch things up to directed graphs

Comment: There's also `IGLayoutReingoldTilford` in IGraph/M with the `"RootVertices"` option. http://i.stack.imgur.com/NiUQr.png  `"RootVertices"` must be a list to support forests (not just trees).

Comment: @Szabolcs off-topic, but do you know a method to make the layout extend more if the number of leaves for the root (381) is much greater than the depth (~5)? Right now it just flattens out and I'd like to be able to see the structure better.

Comment: The GraphLayout doc page describes *lots* fo sub-options, which you should look at. LayeredEmbedding has LeafDistance and LayerSizeFunction for horizontal and vertical scaling, effectively. The IGraph/M equivalent has similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TreeGraph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 2 -> 9, 
  3 -> 6}, VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 1}]
```

Alternatively, use the vertex list  with the desired order as the first argument:

```
TreeGraph[Range[9], {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 6},
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Also `TreePlot` with its optional third and second arguments to specify the root vertex and its position:

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 6}, Top, 1,
  VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. `"RootVertex"` is what I needed.